# JSF 1.1: Avoid escaping special letters

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

I'm maintaining a legacy application created using JSF 1.1 and JBoss Portal..

I cannot seem to figure out how to tell JSF to not escape special letters. For example, the following:

```
This is a test of Danish letters: æ ø å<br/>
<h:outputText value="Test of Danish letters: æ ø å" escape="false" /><br/>
<f:verbatim>This is a test of Danish letters: æ ø å</f:verbatim>
```

produces

```
This is a test of Danish letters: &#230; &#248; &#229;<br/>
This is a test of Danish letters: &#230; &#248; &#229;<br/>
This is a test of Danish letters: &#230; &#248; &#229;
```

(this happens regardless of the escape attribute)..

Now admittedly, the encodings of pages are not explicitly stated, but forcing all pages to use UTF-8 through web.xml does not seem to do anything.

I could unescape the text when I use it in my javascript, however, this requires that I know in advance which characters JSF will escape, so it seems more appropriate to tell JSF to output the characters verbatim in the first place..

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Why is the escaping a problem? It should not be. I'd fix *that* problem instead.

Comment: Because i need, among other things to generate a mailto: link with a subject and display an alert with the text.. These are not auto-converted to the proper letters, but show up as HTML entities in the mail/alert box.

Comment: Are you URL-encoding those HTML entities for the link? (via `<f:param>`)

Comment: I've tried, but JSF throws an exception, complaining that my mailto: link is not a valid URL.. Regardless, this does not solve the underlying issue, because I process the text in javascript in other places, where e.g. an alert is not properly displayed.. Alert is used in the rest of the application, so to ensure consistency I use it also..